# Road vehicles database

Tags: data-request, cars

I'm looking for a regularly updated road vehicles database (cars/trucks/motorcycles etc). It should contain:

- Manufacturer
- Name
- Year
- Dimensions (Length and width and if height is included it would be great, in metric units preferably)
- Few pictures (Optional)

If the database can include all road vehicles ever manufactured, or the popular ones, that would be awesome. I would prefer to download a SQL/CSV file or whatever.

It would be great if the database is updated regularly and Have a REST API, so that if the  car I'm looking for cannot be found in my database, I can check the original database  for updates. It would also be great if the database have a known release schedule so that I could run cron to fetch updates periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never said if seek for a free or you feel comfortable with a paid database?

Anyway, i am currently working with one data provider - mainly using the database for the engine displacements of Land Cruisers.The data is in XML, not CSV but i guess it could be converted.

New, old, regular brands from around the world, concept and prototypes included; 2-3 times a day updated; there's an option for images, i think but you have to ask;

Check the [technical parameters offered](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters). Here's [the demo](https://www.car-database-api.com/media/data.xml)

Comment: I prefer a free sample for testing and a reasonable pricing for production, thank you, I'll check them out and let you know

Comment: I just contacted them, it's an awesome answer, I upvoted it, I'll accept it after they reply just to be sure that they fit my requirements

Comment: just for clarity, a paid database is not open data; free is implied with open data in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.carsxe.com/

The CarsXE API is a RESTful API with millions of vehicles and is updated daily. They provide 4 APIs: vehicle specifications, history, market value and ownership cost.

The vehicle specifications API can return equipment data which would include all of the items you listed except images which would be returned from the photos data object.

XML & JSON but can be converted into a CSV.

Here's an example GET request you can make for a vehicle:

[http://api.carsxe.com/specs?key=CarsXE_API_Key&year=2004&make=toyota&model=camry&include=selections,attributes,colors,photos,equipment](https://api.carsxe.com/docs)